# Adding values from an api call

Tags: javascript, api

So im using an api to get the weekly experience of a certain player, when i call the expHistory it returns this:

```
{
  '2020-09-02': 302,
  '2020-09-01': 834,
  '2020-08-31': 60,
  '2020-08-30': 0,
  '2020-08-29': 0,
  '2020-08-28': 0
}
```

what would be the most efficient way to get the numerical values and add them together

Comment: `Object.values(theVariable).reduce(....)`

Answer (score 1):

```
let obj = {
  '2020-09-02': 302,
  '2020-09-01': 834,
  '2020-08-31': 60,
  '2020-08-30': 0,
  '2020-08-29': 0,
  '2020-08-28': 0
}   

const total = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, current) => acc + current)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.values to get the value and use reduce to sum the values.

```
Object.values({
      '2020-09-02': 302,
      '2020-09-01': 834,
      '2020-08-31': 60,
      '2020-08-30': 0,
      '2020-08-29': 0,
      '2020-08-28': 0
    }).reduce((acc, currentValue) => acc + currentValue, 0)
```